# JS library show/hide element on checkbox status

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JS and am trying to write my own library using this [blog post](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2012/creating-your-own-javascript-library/), and would like a hand. (Apologies if this is too vague for an SO question)

I'm trying to write a function that shows or hides a queried element based on the status of a queried checkbox (and another for a radio button if I can't do it in one method) on a form.

So I'm looking to end up with something like this:

```
$(divId).checkToggle(checkBoxId);
```

So the div will start as hidden. When the checkbox is clicked, the div will toggle to visible. When the checkbox is unchecked, I'd like the div to hide again and any input fields inside it to be cleared (the probably will be only one input field).

I know that this function isn't really going to be very combine-able or reusable, but I would use it so often for just that one thing that I'm going to overlook it.

Okay, enough preamble. [Here's what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/FelixFortis/skT8c/).

Could I have some suggestions on how to change/finish my checkToggle method? Thanks!

Comment: Fairly new to JS and attempting to write a library. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
        if($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $("#myDiv").slideDown(1000);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#myDiv').slideUp(1000);
        }
    });
});
```